# Audio in JavaScript in IE 8

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to play audio(.wav) in my JSP Page.I have to play in IE 8(in https),i found the below code works for me.But at some cases the audio file is not playing in IE 8 in different system.
It works in one machine may not work in another.Is it because of MIME type server is sending.Please advise.

```
<span id=alarmsoundspan></span>
```

```
document.getElementById("alarmsoundspan").innerHTML="<embed src='"+url+"' hidden=true autostart=true loop=false>";
```

Comment: How do you know the MIME is the problem?  What is the MIME type being sent?

Comment: “Is it because of MIME type server is sending?” What MIME type is the server sending? Wait, I'll check... \*hacking your system\*... The MIME type looks good.

Comment: So, you're saying it works on some IE8 machines, but not all?

Comment: @ Rocket Hazmat : yes.MIME type i can check,but its working some times.If we are not forcing the MIME type in server side will it change? Sorry if this a dumb question.

Comment: Could it have something to do with missing/incorrect audio codecs?